# Android FFmpeg reports "file protocol not found"

Tags: android, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert sequence images to video using ffmpeg command in android.
I have build ffmpeg for android and put ffmpeg binary file in /data/local folder.
I am running ffmpeg command using `Runtime.getruntime.execute("mycommand")` in Android.

Stucture of mycommand is like this

```
"/data/local/ffmpeg -r 40 qscale 2 -i /mnt/sdcard/images/img%d.jpg /mnt/sdcard/images/finalvideo.mp4"
```

`mycommand` contains the path of a folder where I placed all my sequence images.  Running this command gives me error "protocol not found".

Also I read that file protocol is default in ffmpeg documentation.

How can I run such commands?

The Error I am getting after running simple command like ffmpeg -i /mnt/sdcard/vid.mp4

```
ffmpeg version 0.11.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Sep 26 2012 11:58:35 with gcc 4.4.3 (GCC)
configuration: --target-os=linux --prefix=/home/esteves/android-ffmpeg --enable-cross-compile --enable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-asm --arch=arm --cc=/home/esteves/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --cross-prefix=/home/esteves/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --disable-stripping --nm=/home/esteves/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm --sysroot=/home/esteves/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --disable-everything --enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-avresample --enable-demuxer=amr --enable-demuxer=aac --enable-demuxer=rawvideo --enable-demuxer=rtsp --enable-muxer=rtsp --enable-muxer=flv --enable-muxer=mpegts --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-demuxer=rtp --enable-demuxer=rtp --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffprobe --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264   libavutil      51. 72.100 / 51. 72.100
libavcodec     54. 55.100 / 54. 55.100
libavformat    54. 25.105 / 54. 25.105
libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
error of main   libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
error of main   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
/mnt/sdcard/vid.mp4: Protocol not found
```

Comment: You forgot a `-` before `qscale`, it should be `-qscale`, and it should be placed *after* the `-i /mnt/…/img%d.jpg` option.

Comment: I tried using this also, but it's giving me same message Protocol not found.I tried another ffmpeg command /data/local/ffmpeg -i /mnt/sdcard/vid.mp4 
that will give information of my video file vid.mp4. But running this command gives me same message Protocol not found.I got this command from link http://www.linuxstall.com/ffmpeg-tutorial/.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the full, uncut output from the new command you're using, not just the error message. Don't forget to indent code with `Ctrl-K` after pasting.

Comment: I update my question with error log at the bottom of question

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid compiling with `--disable-everything`

It will disable all components including protocol support.

## If you must use `--disable-everything`

You will have to manually enable your desired components, such as `--enable-protocols` or in a piecemeal fashion such as `--enable-protocol=file,pipe`. However, this is difficult to do properly because users often forget to enable something they need. See the output of `./configure --help` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It was the ffmpeg compile problem.You should enable protocols releate in configure.
Here is my config you can refer to:

```
export TMPDIR=/Users/yourpath/SourceCode/FFmpeg/tmpdir
NDK=/Users/yourpath/Android/android-ndk-r10d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=/Users/yourpath/Android/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64

CPU=arm
PREFIX=/Users/liuchao/SourceCode/FFmpeg/ffmpeg_install/
#ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
ADDI_CFLAGS="-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp"

function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--target-os=linux \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--arch=arm \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--cc=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--nm=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-asm \
--disable-yasm \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-stripping \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-version3 \
--enable-nonfree
--enable-libx265 \
--enable-w32threads \
--enable-hwaccels \
--enable-neon \
--enable-decoders \
--enable-devices \
--enable-encoders \
--enable-muxers \
--enable-encoder=rawvideo \
--enable-protocols \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-avfilter \
--enable-network \
--enable-avdevice \
--enable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-doc \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly enable most native, internal FFmpeg components unless you manually disable them with a broad disable option (such as `--disable-everything`). Also, it is not recommended to use `--disable-asm` and/or `--disable-yasm` unless you want really slow encoding.

Comment: For anyone that may see this thinks to --enable-asm. Be careful as it supports Text Relocations, which are banned on Android as of Marshmallow. It's a performance hit you have to take as FFmpeg will not do anything to work around: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#text-relocations-enforced-for-api-level-23