# FFMPEG with http url in android

Tags: android

i have use this commond

```
"-loop" ," 1" ,"-framerate", "24", "-t","5","-i","http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/donut.png", "-i",editText.getText().toString(), "-loop", " 1", "-framerate", "24", "-t", "5", "-i", editText3.getText().toString(),
            "-f", "lavfi", "-t", "0.1", "-i", "anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100","-preset", "ultrafast",
        "-filter_complex","[2]scale=480:360,setsar=1[im];[1]scale=480:360,setsar=1[vid];[0]scale=480:360,setsar=1[im]; [im][3][vid][1][im][3] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1",filePath
```

"http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/donut.png" 
use this url to concat to video

getting this error

> ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)   configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102   libavformat    57. 25.100 /
>   57. 25.100   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101   libpostproc    54.  0.100 /
>   54.  0.100 http://api.learn2crack.com/android/images/donut.png: Protocol not found

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023676/android-ffmpeg-log-showing-file-protocol-not-found)

Comment: Some of the build/compiled libraries does not have http protocol support. thus Protocol not found